# ERROR: 42883: function pro_zone_delete(text) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

> **Msg :ERROR: 42883: function pro_zone_delete(text) does not exist**

this error occurs everytime i want to run the following code.am I missing something? I am really exhausted finding out the error.Please help me out.
Thank you.
This is the function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sylvia.pro_zone_delete(
    p_ZoneCode text)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
begin
  delete from zone where zonecode = p_ZoneCode;
end;
$BODY$;
ALTER FUNCTION sylvia.pro_zone_delete(text)
    OWNER TO postgres;

this is the C# code..

    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "pro_zone_delete";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (cmd == null) return UtilDL.GetCommandNotFound();

                foreach (SiteDS.ZoneRow row in sitDS.Zone.Rows)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_ZoneCode", row.ZoneCode);
                    bool bError = false;
                    int nRowAffected = -1;
                    nRowAffected = ADOController.Instance.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, connDS.DBConnections[0].ConnectionID, ref bError);
```

Comment: I don't see `sylvia` schema namein C code...

Comment: actually, i used "set search_path to sylvia" in the procedure..won't it be sufficient?

Comment: should be, but obviously did not work. did you set it per db/user/session/transaction?..